# How should I deal with variable sample length in neural networks during training and prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So my end goal is to build a model with Keras that can predict the gas or brake percentages based on the radar data fed in. However, my radar data can vary from anywhere to 1 point to 16 points (objects) all with their own metadata (velocity, lateral position, etc). An example of my input shape would be `[[4.5, -2.2], [5.6, 1.1]]`, being a list of the radar tracks, velocity and lateral position of that object inside each list.

I know with classification problems we should set this missing data to a class never used except for missing data, though with regression I'm a little confused. If I set missing data to all zeros, how is the model supposed to differentiate between a zero being the velocity of a point, or that the point is missing?

My first thought was to introduce a new data point in all the points and set it to either 0 to 1, corresponding to whether that point is 'real'/to be considered or not. I'm just not sure if that's the best way of going about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think an extra boolean would be necessary as there should only be few cases where the positional data is zero together with the velocity.

However, if you do not want to use zero-padding you could also take advantage of 
Recurrent neural networks (RNNs), which accept a variable input length.

Finally, you can also look at similar questions as answered [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/how-can-neural-networks-deal-with-varying-input-sizes)

Comment: You're right, I removed the extra 'status' variable at the end and replaced the data with 0s and it seems to be doing just the same as before! I guess it figures it out because like you said, 0 m distance from my car is rarely in my training data so it works it out fine. Thanks!